# If a creature with change shape had changed and was in a cage too small for its original form, and then it changed back…

Tags: dnd-5e, shapeshifting

So, I’m thinking of a scenario where a Couatl is change shaped into a cat. And then put in a cage. It’s supposed to be trapped, but what would happen if it changed back into a Couatl? Would the cage bust? Would the Couatl be damaged somehow? Would both the Couatl and the cage be safe? Would the Couatl be unable to change?